# Flex-direction:column doesn't allow children to be scrollable in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I am using display flex for an element (`.outer`) which should adjust its height to the content but must not exceed a certain height (e.g. `100px`).

Once the height is exceeded I want that the content inside to start to scroll vertically.

This behaviour works as expected on Chrome but in Firefox the content wrapper (`.wrapper`) growth to the height of its content (`.list`) and therefore it is not scrollable.

You can try it yourself using this simplified example:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="list">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzOpPZ

---

Setting `max-height` to `height` solves the scroll problem but causes a white space if the content is not high enough.

Comment: Add `.outer {height: 100px;}`

Comment: @fen1x thanks that would solve my problem but unfortunately I need it to be a max-height as it would create a large whitespace otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `min-height:0` to the `.wrapper` class. It will work.

Comment: Wow cool that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad that helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This should fix

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height:0;
}
```