# Flex-direction:column doesn't allow children to be scrollable in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am using display flex for an element (`.outer`) which should adjust its height to the content but must not exceed a certain height (e.g. `100px`).

Once the height is exceeded I want that the content inside to start to scroll vertically.

This behaviour works as expected on Chrome and it was solved in my other  [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372916/flex-directioncolumn-doesnt-allow-children-to-be-scrollable-in-firefox) using Firefox, but in IE11 the content wrapper(`.wrapper`) still growth to the height of its content (`.list`) and therefore it is not scrollable.

You can try it yourself using this simplified example:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="list">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
        <p>5</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Setting `max-height` to `height` solves the scroll problem but causes a white space if the content is not high enough.

Comment: Maybe you need to refresh the browser. I see no whitespace with `height` in either IE11, FF, Chrome and Edge, even with all `<p>` removed

Comment: @RenevanderLende thanks for your comment :) setting a height would not help in my case. In my extended version of this problem, I have a box, which needs to have a auto height to prevent a white space.  This case is not reproduce able in my simplified example, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Add `::before,::after,* { outline: 1px dashed }` to your CSS. The outlines may help you to figure out what is happening. I use this all the time when I need to see what the boxes are doing...